# C++ function to find max value in an array of doubles?

Tags: c++, arrays, x86, floating-point

I frequently find myself writing max value functions that search through an array of doubles I use functions like these to normalize data before graphic display.

Is there a better way to find the max value of an array of doubles? Is there a standard function to find the max value in an array? Are there some intrinsic for this operation? I remember specialized ASM instruction existed in DSP chips.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yep!  There's a function called `std::max_element`:

```
double arr[LENGTH] = /* ... */
double max = *std::max_element(arr, arr + LENGTH);
```

You'll need to `#include <algorithm>` to do this.  That header has a whole bunch of goodies in it, and it's worth taking the time to learn more about the STL containers and algorithms libraries, as they can make your life *so* much easier.

As long as we're on the subject, consider looking into `std::vector` or `std::array` as replacements for raw C++ arrays.  They're safer and a bit easier to use.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm too scared to replace them with std::vectors because my code is auto-vectorizing quite nicely.

Comment: @Misha: Don't be scared, just try it and run a few tests to make sure that your performance is still good.  It's not at all an irrational fear.  We ran into an almost 20% performance drop in some performance critical sections of codes (a lot of looping and floating point ops) and we tracked it down to the move from VS 6 to 2005.  They had checked iterators and (iirc) bounds checking on by default.